# Call a servlet from a JSP and return back to the same line in a JSP

Tags: jsp

Is it possible to call a servlet from a JSP and the servlet returns to the same line from where it was called in the same JSP ?

Like a function calling another function in c/c++..

Answer (score 1):

Use `<jsp:include>`.

```
<p>Blah blah.</p>
<jsp:include page="/servletURL" />
<p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
```

Note that a servlet which is supposed to generate HTML is more than often a smell. Also, if the servlet is intented to preprocess some data, you should rather call it the other way round: call the servlet by its URL instead of the JSP and let servlet forward the request to JSP. See also [our servlets tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).